# Swift, lot's of use of unresolved identifier after git clone

Tags: swift

I have clone a project from git which worked fine on another machine, however after cloning I receive tons of "use of unresolved identifier" like so:

[image]

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Post your code, not screenshots of your code.  Post your errors, not screenshots of your errors.

Comment: Did you add/commit/push everything that is necessary on "another machine"? Check `git status` over there. Make sure that you added everything that is necessary to get the right dependencies.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have, and it is weird because Xcode complains about stuff like UIButton, CGRect, UIControlEvents etc all of which should be accessible even if I missed adding some files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `import UIKit` at the top of the file. That is often the source of this kind of error, because all UIxxx classes are missing.

Comment: When I had the Facebook SDK added to my project everything compiled without the import of UIKit. Once it was removed, I had to manually import it. That was causing my confusion, thanks!